# Why doesn't `su -` re-read /etc/environment?

Tags: linux, su, pam

I have the following line in `/etc/environment`:

```
AAABBB=cccddd
```

When I login using the text console, the variable is set, I don't even need to reboot. But if I do `su -`, the variable is cleared. Why is that?

I have this on ArchLinux and on CentOS 6 and 7.

[here](https://superuser.com/a/339652/233620) grawity says:

> Logging out and back in would apply the changes

But issuing the `su` command with dash is that very thing!

I'm really unhappy that `su -` **clears** the variable. Is there a way to make su behave better? One workaround is to duplicate the record in `/etc/profile.d`. It's not enough to have the record in profile and not `/etc/environment`, because there are cases when profile scripts aren't sourced, e.g. `scp`.

**Upd**

```
[root@reallin ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/su
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            required        pam_unix.so
account         required        pam_unix.so
session         required        pam_unix.so
[root@reallin ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/su-l
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            required        pam_unix.so
account         required        pam_unix.so
session         required        pam_unix.so
```

Comment: Have you tried `su -` with `-m` or `-p` flags?

Comment: @coffeMug I don't want to preserve my env. I want it to reinitialize honoring /etc/environment

Comment: What is the shell of the `root` user (which is whom you're logging in as with `su -`)?  Is the variable set when `root` ordinarily logs in?

Comment: @Kusalananda 1) `/bin/bash` ; 2) yes

Comment: @basin Do you have `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` file in your system? If yes, try to set the variable in that file and see if it works. Format is like `Name     DEFAULT=value`

Comment: @coffeMug same behavior: it works with console logon, but not with su command

Comment: Strange. I just tested in my machine and works for me!! How does your su file under /etc/pam.d look like?

Comment: @coffeMug see the updated footer of my question

Answer (score 3):

Although `su -l <user>` works fine on my system, I noticed that `sudo su -l <user>` – although it picks up ".profile" just fine – seemed to cause the same problem you describe of clearing variables supposedly set universally in "/etc/environment".

I was able to get what appeared to be a full login (execution of the ".profile" of `<user>`  plus the variables from "/etc/environment") by doing:

```sh
sudo -i -u <user>
```

Comment: Are there any nuances to the difference of `sudo` and `su` here that one should be aware of?